# Jetpack Compose rememberSaveable() leads to crash when an app goes to background

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've updated compose version to 1.0.0-beta01 and faced with the crash when an app goes to background

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
> androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutableStateImpl@efa375c
> at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1885)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1092)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1832)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:943)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:925)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1797)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:943)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:925)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1797)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1092)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1832)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:975)
> at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
> at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1044)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1801)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:975)
> at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
> at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1044)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1801)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:975)
> at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
> at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
> at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4389)
> at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

```
var email by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
```

If I just change rememberSaveable() to remember() everything works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug whose fix will be released in beta02: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180042685

There's a temporary workaround [mentioned](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180042685#comment4) there, which you can do:

```
var email by rememberSaveable(saver = stateSaver()) { mutableStateOf("") }
```

Where `stateSaver()` is defined as:

```
fun <T> stateSaver() = Saver<MutableState<T>, Any>(
    save = { state -> state.value ?: "null" },
    restore = { value ->
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        mutableStateOf((if (value == "null") null else value) as T)
    }
)
```