# App crashes when put in background on every screen that uses rememberSaveable with mutableStateOf

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

This crash is seen when using something like `var selectedOption by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }` inside a NavHost destination.

Currently using `"androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.2`

This issue has been seen before and is similar to [this other question asked in 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547601/jetpack-compose-remembersaveable-leads-to-crash-when-an-app-goes-to-background)

However, the fixes suggested then do not work now and also the [suggestions from this Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180042685?pli=1) do not solve the issue.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = [Landroidx.compose.runtime.MutableState;)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1833)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1780)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1045)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1729)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:896)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:878)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1694)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:896)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:878)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1694)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1045)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1729)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:928)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1584)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1253)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:997)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1698)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:928)
    ...
    at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4505)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: androidx.compose.runtime.ParcelableSnapshotMutableState
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1434)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1230)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1828)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1780) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1045) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1729) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:896) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:878) 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same crash today.

**Quickfix** => If you don't need your variable to survive configuration change but only recomposition, you can replace `rememberSaveable` with `remember`.

Regardings what's the cause of this, it's written (not clearly) here => https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-saving#ui-logic

> `rememberSaveable` stores UI element state in a Bundle through the saved
> instance state mechanism.
>
> It is able to store primitive types to the bundle automatically. If
> your state is held in a type that is not primitive, like a data class,
> you can use different storing mechanisms, such as using the Parcelize
> annotation, using Compose APIs like listSaver and mapSaver, or
> implementing a custom saver class extending Compose runtime Saver
> class. See the Ways to store state documentation to learn more about
> these methods.

Basically, you're saving a custom object via rememberSaveable and said object will be put in a Bundle which without modification on your object, can't save it.

**Permanent** proper fix => implement https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize (note it's 3 lines of code max in a data class)